# Flutter dynamic widgets

Tags: flutter

Could it be possible to create widgets dynamically in Flutter using an external json file?

Something like this:

> myApp.exe -file myWidgets.json

Comment: There are numerous strategies for this, but only succeeding at the most basic level.  What makes widgets interesting is shared data and interactions. To reduce these down to a JSON representation will run afoul of the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner-platform_effect and will be predictably unsatisfying.

Comment: Yes, I want something basic.